# Connectivity service interface in common library code

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a project that has a WPF and a mobile app, and there is also a .net standard library which has all the service and data layer which is shared between the two projects. I need to add a IConnectivityService Interface in the this common library project so that, before making a call to the server I can check if there is a connection available, and I also have an event handler in this interface that gets called when there is a change in connectivity.

```
public interface IConnectivityService
{
    bool IsConnected { get; }

    event EventHandler<ConnectivityChangedEventArgs> ConnectivityChanged;
}
```

The event handler for the Xamarin side do look like the above.

```
public interface IConnectivityService
{
    bool IsConnected { get; }

    event EventHandler ConnectivityChanged;
}
```

And for WPF it need to be this way.

**Note: ConnectivityChangedEventArgs is a xamarin implementation and I would want to avoid from the shared code**

Whats the best way to handle this? I ideally would like to have this as a shared code, so that I can use it in my service layer

Comment: Use the second declaration for both platforms.

Comment: @LibinJoseph: If you don't want to add `ConnectivityChangedEventArgs` to the shared .NET Standard library, you will obviously have to go with the second implementation. What's the issue?

Comment: Guys. Thanks for the comments. I did the same. I was really tired on the day, and my brains were just not working.